# Operations with probability distributions

Tags: probability-distributions

I had an idea that passes by declaring a new type of **computer variable** (like Integer, Double, etc.) **that represents a statistical probability distribution (PDF)**, for that I would need to define the basic operations; sum, multiplication, inverse and negation.

The problem is that I have no idea of how to define such operations or if that is even possible. (I'm electrical engineer...)

So the question is; How to `sum`, `multiply`, `inverse` and `negate` probability distributions, or where can I learn how to do it. A numerical approach would be sufficient.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not trivial. For example density function of sum of two continuous variables is [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) of densities of these variables.

Comment: You can study more about sums of random variables at http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter7.pdf

Answer (score 1):

A reasonable interpretation of "sum" or "multiply" for two probability distributions is the distribution of the sum or product of two independent random variables with those distributions.  However, there's no natural way to have an "inverse".